# Can't change values of numeric cells via Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Here's my script for some Google sheet:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var value = e.range.getValue();
  if (~value.indexOf("*")) {
    e.range.setValue("with *");
  } else {
    e.range.setValue("without *");
  }
}
```

When I type some string to cell — script changes value to "with *" or "without *", but when I change value to "1", "1.5" or some another numeric value — cell don't changes.

How can I change numeric values to "without *"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when the numeric characters like `1` and `1.5` are inputted, the `value` is retrieved as a number. So in order to work your script, please convert `value` to a string.

So can you try as follows?

#### From :

```
if (~value.indexOf("*")) {
```

#### To :

```
if (~value.toString().indexOf("*")) {
```

or

```
if (~String(value).indexOf("*")) {
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.